# R rbindlist fill=TRUE option doesn't work with integer64

Tags: r, data.table

fill=TRUE option of rbindlist doesn't work with integer64 entries.

For example, the below command gives an error.

> rbindlist(list(data.table(a=1), data.table(a=1, b=as.integer64(1))), fill=TRUE)
>
> Error:
>
> Class attributes at column 2 of input list at position 2 does not match with column 2 of input list at position 1. Coercion of objects of class 'factor' alone is handled internally by rbind/rbindlist at the moment.

However, when column b was different class type, then rbindlist works smoothly.

Is there a setting to fix this issue, or is the issue already fixed at some version of R?

My sessionInfo() shows:

> R version 3.1.2(2014-10-31)
>
> Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> other attached packages:
>
> bit64_0.9-4    bit_1.1-12   data.table_1.9.6 ...

Comment: Your code worked for me with R 3.2.5 and data.table 1.10.0 and bit64 0.9-5.

Comment: I see the same as the OP on bit64 1.1-12, data.table 1.9.6, r 3.2.3, but based on lmo's comment, an upgrade will probably fix.

Comment: Thank you all. I will update and try.